# How do I remove all items from a jComboBox without triggering an action listener?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

When I try to clear the items listed in my `JComboBox` it triggers my `ActionListener` that is tied to the combo box. I have another function that gets called recursively as a result and is generating a duplicate value. Is there a way to temporarily disable the action listener and remove everything from the `JComboBox` without triggering an event?

```java
jComboBox_database.removeAllItems();
```

---

```java
jComboBox_database.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
jComboBox_database.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jComboBox_databaseActionPerformed(evt);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware, you cannot "disable" an `ActionListener`.

The `ActionListener` will be notified whenever the `JComboBox` selection changes. Clearing the items also sets the "selected item" to null, thus invoking your `actionPerformed` method.

Assuming you only want to call your recursive method when you actually select a value, maybe you should implement [ItemListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) instead.

```java
jComboBox_database.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            jComboBox_databaseActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    }
});
```

Of-course, you may need to also change the parameter to your method `jComboBox_databaseActionPerformed` since an `ItemEvent` is not exactly the same as an `ActionEvent`.

Another alternative would be to simply call method [removeActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#removeActionListener-java.awt.event.ActionListener-) before you clear the `JComboBox` and then call method `addActionListener` after.

Comment: Indeed, don't use an `ActionListener`, but an `ItemListener` instead.

Comment: ItemListener worked great! Thanks @Abra and @OlivierGrégoire!

Answer (score 0):

You could change the ActionCommand of your JComboBox before and after you `removeAllItems()`.

```
String oldCommand = jComboBox_database.getActionCommand();
jComboBox_database.setActionCommand("cmdIgnore");
jComboBox_database.removeAllItems();
jComboBox_database.setActionCommand(oldCommand);
```

and in your ActionListener:

```
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if( ! "cmdIgnore".equals(evt.getActionCommand())) {
        jComboBox_databaseActionPerformed(evt);
    }
}
```